# FQL is_app_user behavior change?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

For a couple of months now I've been able to use the following:

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

in order to get a user's friends who use the app. This has been working pretty well, up until recently (a couple of days ago?) when many of the results disappeared. It turns out this was because now the "Visibility of app" setting affects whether or not I can get an accurate is_app_user result.

Was this an intentional change recently? I'm fairly certain I didn't change my query recently.

Also, is there a way to request that the visibility of app be "friends" when requesting permissions to facebook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a very recent bug on Facebook and they're aware and trying to fix it ASAP:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/279021535572777